# Mitagation strategies for password-stealers and ransomware

Tags: security, permissions, passwords

I'd like to protect the contents of my NAS from Ransomware and other attacks on data. In addition to the standard advice (updates, anti-malware, least-privilege, lecturing the kids and their friends...), I've made the files in my library read-only to all my windows users, and administer it via the NAS web front-end instead. This is largely because most common ransomware kits steal and break password hashes (ie mimikatz), to use in further exploitation of the network.

Now, I'd like to use a piece of windows software to curate my library (put things away, rename files, etc), but it would require a windows user with write access to the files.

Does anyone have any strategies (other than backups, which are cost-prohibitive) for enabling writing to high-value data-sources without leaving password hashes lying around for anyone to steal?

Comment: Best solution is an offline backup of the data, wipe and restore if you get infected.

Comment: Yeah. why does tape have to be soooo expensive?

Comment: tape is a small and shrinking market, so manufacturing units and media do not scale to low costs.  our backups is 1: offline replica on 2nd identical media, 2: online replica in the cloud, 3: offline reverse-increment (replica is most recent and incrementals go backward) that migrates to cloud.

Comment: I'm afraid the scale of the situation is most of the problem. It would take 1.7 years to populate an initial cloud replica at max bandwidth 24x7, and I simply can't afford to duplicate the hardware. I do buy top of the line drives with 5-year warranties, and i monitor my SMART data to catch problems as quickly as possible, but that's about all the protection I can afford.

Comment: Top of the line drives fail almost as often as lower spec drives - are you at least using a RAID level other then RAID0 or 5?

Comment: Just use an inexpensive usb hard drive or two, only connect it when making backups of restore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An offline backup can't be attacked, it's the only 100% sure way to ensure your data survives a ransomware attack.

The only next best solution, if you have no trust for the Windows authentication system at all, but still want to use a Windows system, is to dedicate a separate, well-controlled system and only allow an account on that system to have read/write access, and never use that account on any other system.

Well-controlled may go so far as to disconnect from the Internet and your internal network and use flash drives to transfer data, or you could try maintaining an installation of Windows in a VM that's only used to interact with your NAS and doesn't have a connection to the rest of your network.

Comment: I agree on backups, but they are just non-actionable for my volume of data and budget. Your other thought has some merit. I might be able to do a VM on a VLAN (my esxi box has a spare nic). A dedicated management station may be the key.

Comment: Look into snapshotting on the NAS (if it supports zfs or lvm). Regular snapshots can greatly mitigate the loss.

Comment: You talk about backups being cost prohibitive on your high value data sources. You are suffering from cognitive dissonance. Similarly worrying about password hashes being left on disk while ignoring risk of theft, fire, flooding, malicious trusted users. You may want to find a more experienced IT person to help assess the risk profile.

Comment: Also look into getting a bunch of cheaper, older hard drives from older systems (think older 320GB laptop drives or similar) and treating them as tapes.